# Disable a specific checkbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to request assistance on how can I disable a specific checkbox.

*Scenario:*

1. If I clicked the 'Yes to all' checkbox - the other checkbox will be disabled (Q1 to Q4)
2. If I selected one or more on the Q1 to Q4 checkbox - 'Yes to all' checkbox will be disabled

*Code:*

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).attr('disabled', '');
  } else {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', '');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1" />Q1
<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2" />Q2
<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3" />Q3
<input type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4" />Q4

<input type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA" />Yes to all
```

Comment: What's your question about the given code?

Comment: I need to add an 'id' tag on the script to separate 'Q1-Q4' and 'Yes to all' checkbox given the scenario.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use jquery?

Comment: yes, because I will use it on Salesforce

Comment: "I  need to add an 'id' tag on the script" - sounds fine. What keeps you from doing exactly that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check weather the checkboxes selected or not as per your requirement,
Condition 1: if question selected length is more than 1, then disable the YTA
condition 2: if YTA is selected then disable all the Questions

If need anything else, please let me know.

```js
$('.yta').change(function() {
if($('.yta:checked').length){
  $('.q').attr('disabled', true);
}else {
 $('.q').removeAttr("disabled");
}
});


$('.q').change(function() {
 if($('.q:checked').length){
  $('.yta').attr('disabled', true);
  }else {
  $('.yta').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="q" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1" />Q1
<input class="q" type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2" />Q2
<input class="q" type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3" />Q3
<input class="q" type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4" />Q4

<input class="yta" type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA" />Yes to all
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer with my philosophy:

- Avoid jQuery if you can
- Use small functions that do one thing
- Have in mind that the same should work when used multiple times in a document
- Prevent magic values in your code
- Encapsulate as much as possible

So this seems like overkill, but this works

```js
{
  function checkAnswers(qNames, allName) {
    const qSelector = qNames.map(e => `[name="${e}"]`).join(',')
    const allSelector = `[name="${allName}"]`
    const selector = `${qSelector},${allSelector}`;

    const getValue = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).filter(e => e.checked).map(e => ({[e.name]: e.value}))
    const checkQ = value => value.map(e => Object.keys(e)[0]).filter(value => qNames.includes(value)).length > 0;
    const checkAll = value =>  value.map(e => Object.keys(e)[0]).includes(allName)

    const qDisable = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(qSelector)).forEach(e => e.disabled = true)
    const qEnable = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(qSelector)).forEach(e => e.disabled = false)

    const allDisable =() => document.querySelector(allSelector).disabled = true
    const allEnable = () => document.querySelector(allSelector).disabled = false    

    return e => {
      if (!e.target.closest(selector)) {return}

      const value = getValue();
      if (checkQ(value)) {
        allDisable();
      } else if (checkAll(value)) {
        qDisable()
      } else {
        allEnable();
        qEnable();
      }
    }
  }  

  
  let qNames = ['QA1','QA2','QA3','QA4']
  let allName = 'QAYTA'
  
  document.addEventListener('change', checkAnswers(qNames, allName))

  qNames = ['QB1','QB2','QB3','QB4']
  allName = 'QBYTA'
  
  document.addEventListener('change', checkAnswers(qNames, allName))
}
```

```css
:disabled + label {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="QA1" name="QA1" value="1"/><label for="QA1">Question 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QA2" name="QA2" value="2"/><label for="QA2">Question 2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QA3" name="QA3" value="3"/><label for="QA3">Question 3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QA4" name="QA4" value="4"/><label for="QA4">Question 4</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="QAYTA" name="QAYTA" value="YTA"/><label for="QAYTA">Yes to all</label>


<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QB1" name="QB1" value="1"/><label for="QB1">Question 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QB2" name="QB2" value="2"/><label for="QB2">Question 2</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QB3" name="QB3" value="3"/><label for="QB3">Question 3</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="QB4" name="QB4" value="4"/><label for="QB4">Question 4</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="QBYTA" name="QBYTA" value="YTA"/><label for="QBYTA">Yes to all</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="q1_q4" type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1"/>Q1
<input class="q1_q4" type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2"/>Q2
<input class="q1_q4" type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3"/>Q3
<input class="q1_q4" type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4"/>Q4

<input class="yta" type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA"/>Yes to all

<script>

$(".q1_q4").on('change', function(){
  $(".yta").attr("disabled","disabled");
});

$(".yta").on('change', function(){
  $(".q1_q4").attr("disabled","disabled");
});

</script>
```

Comment: If the user uncheck the checkbox ??

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Do you mean, if user wants to uncheck the checkbox?
I have only added the code according to the information given.

Answer (score 0):

**See the perfect answer.**

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is('input[name="QYTA"]')) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('input[type=checkbox][name!="QYTA"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('input[type=checkbox][name!="QYTA"]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  } else {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('input[type=checkbox][name="QYTA"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else if($('input[type=checkbox][name!="QYTA"]:checked').length == 0) {
      $('input[type=checkbox][name="QYTA"]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1" />Q1
<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2" />Q2
<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3" />Q3
<input type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4" />Q4

<input type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA" />Yes to all
```

Comment: My Answer is perfect as OP wants. still, someone has downvoted it. please don't do it if the answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.prop` function in jQuery to add and remove the disabled attribute easily. You would need to refine the selectors if you are using other checkboxes on the same page.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if (this.name == "QYTA" && this.checked) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name!="QYTA"]').prop("disabled", true);
  } else if (this.name != "QYTA" && this.checked) {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name="QYTA"]').prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1" />Q1
<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2" />Q2
<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3" />Q3
<input type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4" />Q4

<input type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA" />Yes to all
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set up `onchange` event handler for each checkbox.

And then depending on the element which triggered the `onchange` event to perform a different operation.

if `QYTA` trigger the `onchange` then disable the `Q1` to `Q4` checkbox.
Else
disable the `QYTA` checkbox.

I make use of the logic difference between the `checked` and `disabled` attribute.

Here is my solution:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
  $(this).on('change', function() {
    if (this.name=='QYTA'){
        for (let i=1;i<5;i++){
            $("input[type='checkbox'][name='Q"+i+"']").attr('disabled', this.checked);
        }
    } else{
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='QYTA']").attr('disabled', this.checked);
    }   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1"/>Q1
<input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2"/>Q2
<input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3"/>Q3
<input type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4"/>Q4

<input type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA"/>Yes to all
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

hope help u

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                var el = $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[name='QYTA']"));
                var elAl = $("input[name='QYTA']");
                if($(this).not(elAl).length == 0) {
                    if(elAl.is(':checked')){
                        el.attr('disabled',true);
                    } else {
                        $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                } else if(el.is(':checked')){
                    elAl.attr('disabled',true);
                } else {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
             
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Q1" value="1"/>Q1
        <input type="checkbox" name="Q2" value="2"/>Q2
        <input type="checkbox" name="Q3" value="3"/>Q3
        <input type="checkbox" name="Q4" value="4"/>Q4

        <input type="checkbox" name="QYTA" value="YTA"/>Yes to all
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it